# Unreal Engine 4.22 C++ Code suggestion in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

i can't get Unreal C++ code suggestion in visual studio c++ 2017 & Clion

Comment: What is an “Unreal C++ code suggestion”?

Comment: You mean code autocomplete and suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't do anything,
Me too faced this problem.  I will re-install My windows and follow all these steps.

my opinion is please delete remove windows and reinstall windows again

Open the link and you will understand perfectly...
[Desktop Development With C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15iBP.jpg)

[Game Development With Unity and And Game Development with C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcIGR.jpg)